# OpenCV chain code in Optical Character Recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to write an Optical Character Recognition (OCR) code that uses chain codes to identify characters. I'm using skeletonized characters and not boundaries, as such there will be intersections. I've tried using cvFindContours but it doesn't cater to my problem.

Can anyone help me with this? Maybe a tip to use certain openCV functions. I'm new to the library.

Comment: Did you try cvFindContours with the parameter to extract chain codes?